# How to determine whether an object was created using an object literal or an Object constructor call?

Tags: javascript, string-literals, object-literal, function-literal

More specifically, how would you determine if a certain object was created using a literal or not?

```
var s1 = new String();
var s2 = ""; // Literal

var o1 = new Object();
var o2 = {}; // Literal

var f1 = new Function();
var f2 = function(){}; // Literal
```

Obviously if you compare any two above, for example:

```
var o1 = new Object();
var o2 = {};

alert(o1 == o2);
alert(o1 === o2);

alert(typeof o1);
alert(typeof o2);
```

... The first two alerts will show `false` while the last two alerts will give `[Object object]`

Say for example, if I wanted to do this:

```
function isLiteral(obj, type) {
    // ...
}
```

... how would one go about doing this?

<sup>I **have** taken a look at [How to determine if an object is an object literal in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173549/how-to-determine-if-an-object-is-an-object-literal-in-javascript), but it does not answer my question.</sup>

Comment: Did you try this instead answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Comment: You would also get false if `o1 = {}` and `o2 = {}`, or if `o1 = new Object()` and `o2 = new Object()`. Javascript checks for reference equality. Afaik there is no difference between an object and an object literal.

Comment: @ElianEbbing: I rephrased my question, hope it helps.

Comment: One last thing, there is no such thing as a "function literal". The RHS of `var f2 = function(){};` is a **function expression**, which is very similar to a function declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, the difference between these two lines:

```
var s1 = new String();
var s2 = ""; // Literal
```

...and the difference between these two lines:

```
var o1 = new Object();
var o2 = {}; // Literal
```

...are two different concepts.

The first is the difference between a **primitive value** and an **object**, while the second is... different syntax for the same thing.

---

Strings, numbers and booleans are **primitive values**, not **objects**, but can be wrapped as objects using `new String()`, `new Number()` or `new Boolean()`. So for these, `typeof` will return different values:

```
var s1 = new String();
typeof s1; // "object"
var s2 = "";
typeof s2; // "string"
```

---

However, for Object and Function, the difference between:

```
var o1 = new Object();
var o2 = {};
```

... is in syntax only.

Both `o1` and `o2` have the same `prototype`, and the same `constructor`, making them indistinguishable at runtime.

Comment: This answer is missing a conclusion. Presumably, "sorry, but there is no distinction".

Comment: Say I had `var o2 = {}, o3 = new Object(o2);` Is there a way to tell if `o3` is indeed a new object of `o2`?

Comment: @Shaz, nope, because `o2===o3`.

Comment: @Shaz, to clarify, `o3` is *not* a new object of `o2` at all. This is the tricky side of `new`... it doesn't necessarily mean a new object is created.

Comment: it may be better to explain that per ECMA-262, if o2 references an object, then `new Object(o2)` simply returns a reference to that object. Assigning the result to o3 means that o2 and o3 reference the same object.