# how does prototype property of function effects the constructor property of an object?

Tags: javascript, oop

i have the below code snippet

```
function Dad(){

  this.name="i am dad";
}

function Son(){
   this.nameOfChild="child";   
}

var sonBeforeInheritance= new Son();
alert(sonBeforeInheritance.constructor);  //outputs Son class

//inheritance done
Son.prototype= new Dad();

var sonObj= new Son();
alert(sonObj.constructor); //outputs Dad class    
alert(sonBeforeInheritance.constructor);  //outputs Son class
```

my undestanding please answer with true/false and explanation:

1. although functions in js are also objects but the objects which are created with **new keyword** and **prototype** object are the only ones which have access to the property called **constructor** i.e. **sonObj.constructor and Son.prototype.constructor** is valid
2. function in js have an object called **prototype** which objects defined with new keyword dont have i.e. **sonObj** above doesn't have **prototype** i.e. **sonObj.prototype is "undefined"**
3. now **constructor** points to the class which was used to make the object? if true then why does sonObj.constructor gives me dad class? one might say that prototype of Son has changed then is the **Son.prototype.constructor** and  **"instance of Son".constructor** point to same object?
4. Why should I write **Son.prototype.constructor=Son** after inheritance?

Comment: Have you read the **Related** questions in the sidebar? In particular, it looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541204/prototype-and-constructor-object-properties?rq=1 should address most of your questions.

Comment: i wanted clarification on what happens before and after inheritance thats why i posted it from the explanation below i could understand that every obj created with new ref to constructor obj which is  class.prototype.constructor but if class.prototype.constructor is   overwritten then obj created before inheritance will continue pointing to the old one which is not talked about in the link you have given @Barmar

Comment: You should not create an instance of Parent to set the prototype part of inheritance for Child use `Son.prototype = Object.create(Dad.prototype)` instead. To inherit instance specific members or re use Parent constructor code in Child call the Parent constructor: `Parent.call(this,arguments);` Re assigning prototype does not affect already created instances but mutating the prototype does. More information about constructor functions and prototype here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> although functions in js are also objects but the objects which are
>   created with new keyword and prototype object are the only ones which
>   have access to the property called constructor

No. Most objects in js do have a `.constructor` property, they inherit it from their prototype. Also plain objects created by `{}` inherit fro `Object.prototype` and their `.constructor` will point to `Object`, just as arrays inherit `.constructor == Array` from the `Array.prototype` or functions inherit `.constructor == Function` from `Function.prototype`. They don't need to be created by `new` necessarily.

> function in js have an object
>   called prototype which objects defined with new keyword dont have i.e.
>   sonObj above doesn't have prototype i.e. sonObj.prototype is
>   "undefined"

True. That's [how `.prototype` works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/1048572).

> now constructor points to the class which was used to
>   make the object?

Not necessarily. `.constructor` is an ordinary property on the prototype so that it will be inherited by the instances, and is *initialized* to be the function to which the prototype object belongs. Both the `.prototype` and `.constructor` are overwritable, though.

> if true then why does sonObj.constructor gives me dad
>   class?

Because you've overwritten `Son.prototype` with an object whose `.constructor` property is not `Son`, but the inherited value `Dad` (you've changed it to be a `new Dad` instance - [questionable, btw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572))

> one might say that prototype of Son has changed then is the
>   Son.prototype.constructor and "instance of Son".constructor point to
>   same object?

Yes.

> Why should I write Son.prototype.constructor=Son after
>   inheritance?

To fix it and make it work like you initially expected. See also [What is the `constructor` property really used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12622137/1048572).

Comment: `.constructor` will point to whatever constructed the object, be it `Object`, `Array`, or `myFunc`.

Comment: @Mosho: Unless it doesn't, like `(new Son).constructor == Dad` :-) That's what I said, yes

Comment: well, your first answer is a bit misleading, that's what I was referring to.

Comment: @Mosho: I've overhauled that paragraph now. Better?