# what javascript prototype.constructor for?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Here is the inheritance structure I setup for testing:

```
function A() {
    this.a = 1;
}

function B() {
    this.b = 2;
}

B.prototype = new A();
//B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

Below is what I tried in Chrome's JavaScript Console:

```
>var b = new B;
>b instanceof A
true

>B.prototype.constructor
function A() {
    this.a = 1;
}
```

My question is what's the purpose to setup B.prototype.constructor =  B? Which I've already commented out? It doesn't seem to break the inheritance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541204/prototype-and-constructor-object-properties

Answer (score 0):

`B.prototype.constructor = B` results in `instanceof`' giving the expected results, but there are better ways of doing that. There is some discussion of this at: [Convention for prototype inheritance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402538/convention-for-prototype-inheritance-in-javascript/402919#402919)