# Inspecting custom exceptions

Tags: javascript, exception

I'm trying to create a custom exception with some useful debug information:

```
var customError = function(name, message) {

    this.message = message;
    this.name = name;

    this.prototype = new Error(); // to make customError "inherit" from the 
                                  // default error
};

throw new customError('CustomException', 'Something went wrong');
```

But all I'm getting are fuzzy messages in the console:

**IE**: "SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught "

**Firefox**: "uncaught exception: [object Object]"

What do I need to change in order to get something useful out of my exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong usage of prototype:

```
var customError = function(name, message) {    
    this.message = message;
    this.name = name;
};

customError.prototype = new Error(); // to make customError "inherit" from the 
                                     // default error

throw new customError('CustomException', 'Something went wrong');
```

`prototype` is a property of the constructor (`customError`), not of the constructed object (`this`), see ECMA sec [4.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2.1) and [4.3.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.5).

Comment: Thanks. IE still gives me the same undescriptive message though. Perhaps it's just one of all the downsides with IE :)

Comment: Btw, do i need to add `customError.prototype.constructor = customError` or is it not required?

Comment: @Johan: Usually it's not required. I believe I saw something like that once, but I cannot remember where. Meanwhile, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402538/convention-for-prototype-inheritance-in-javascript. It's usually non-standard.